# Apply pre-commit only on the local repository?

Tags: git

Using Git, I have a pre-commit hook that I filled with `mvn clean install`.

I aim to test if this command executes without error before pushing to the remote repo.

The problem is that this command applies to my current directory, not to the local git repository (that consists of only the added files). So, sometimes I got an error because on some files that I did not add, while there is no error without these files.

So my question is how can I apply a pre-commit of `mvn clean install` that applies only on the added files to the local repo ?

Comment: Doesn't that depend very much on the hook itself?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Do you mean that I need to change the command in the hook ?

Comment: I mean that I have no idea because you are asking about something I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Example of pre-commit hook shell script: https://gist.github.com/dahjelle/8ddedf0aebd488208a9a7c829f19b9e8

Notice line 3:

```
$(git diff --cached --name-only | grep -E '\.(js|jsx)$')
```

This grabs the files of a `git commit ...` piped to filter only .js or .jsx files. You can modify this script and remove the piping.

On line 5: modify the `node_modules/...` line with your `mvn clean install`.

Modify the script as needed.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example that might match your use case more clearly: https://eing.github.io/technology/2016/01/28/Git-Pre-Commit-Hooks-Part1/

```sh
{ echo "
git stash -q --keep-index
# Using "mvn test" to run all unit tests and run plugins to assert
#   * code coverage threshold >= 85% (using surefire, enforcer plugins)
#   * FindBugs at low threshold errors (using findbugs-maven-plugin)
#   * Checkstyle has 0 errors (using maven-checkstyle-plugin)
mvn clean install test
RESULTS=\$?
# Perform checks
git stash pop -q
if [ \$RESULTS -ne 0 ]; then
  echo Error: Commit criteria not met with one or more of the following issues,
  echo 1. Failure\(s\) in unit tests
  echo 2. Failure to meet 85% code coverage
  echo 3. Failure to meet low FindBugs threshold
  echo 4. Failure to meet 0 Checkstyle errors
  exit 1
fi
# You shall commit
exit 0"
} > pre-commit.sh
pushd .git/hooks
ln -s ../../pre-commit.sh pre-commit
chmod u+x pre-commit
popd
```

Comment: When I add ``mvn clean install`` it execute the commad for each added file. I want to execute it only once for all the commited files

Comment: How are you committing? Are you adding all the files all at once or one at a time? This script can do it all at once. What is your process? Do you add one file then commit or do you add all files then commit?

Comment: Here is my process : ``git add file1 file2`` then ``git commit -m "update message"`` and I want that before commiting it check whether ``mvn clean install`` executes without errors only on the state of the repo after adding file1 file2, not all the directory. Then I would add file3 and I want to repeat the same process, on each commit basically.

Comment: @devPsycho Please take a look at my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks. Well I think I need a lighter version. 
``git stash -q --keep-index 
mvn clean install git stash pop -q
exit 0
``
Could you confirm that it checks whether mvn executes correctly on the commited files ?